# Prove that there are maximum 4 points on every convex closed Jordan curve $C$ which avoids intersection under certain rotaitions

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, curves, plane-curves

Prove that there are maximum 4 points on an arbitrary given closed convex Jordan curve of $C$ on a plane which for each one like $p$ we have the following property:

If we rotate $C$ around $p$ by $\frac {\pi} {2}$   clockwise on the plane then the created curve $C'$ has no intersection with $C$ exept on $p$.

What if we change $90^{\circ}$ by another degree or change $C$ to a non convex closed jordan curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:This proof is only valid for convex curves.

First consider $P$ and $Q$ are two points on $C$ satisfying the condition ,then there are two angles $\angle lPl'$ = $\angle hQh'$ = $90^{\circ}$ which $P$ is inside $\angle hQh'$ and $Q$ is inside $\angle lPl'$. (Why?)

let $A$ intersection of the semilines $l$ ,$h$ and $B$ intersection of semilines $l'$ ,$h'$ ,now we can easily see that $C$ is inscribed in convex quadrilateral $APBQ$.(why?)

there are two options now:

1.one of two angles $\widehat{PAQ}$ ,$\widehat{PBQ}$ are less than $90^{\circ}$ and the other is bigger.

let
$\widehat{PAQ}$ < $90^{\circ}$ and $\widehat{PBQ}$ > $90^{\circ}$.
now we can see for every point $b \in C \not= P,Q$ inside or on the triangle $\triangle PBQ$ does not have the condition because $\widehat{PbQ}$ > $\widehat{PBQ}$ > $90^{\circ}$ and $P,Q \in C$.

so if there are another points which have the condition ,they must be inside or on the $\triangle PAQ$ .we consider another point having the condition $R \in C$ among all $C$ points inside or on the triangle $\triangle PAQ$ which the angle $\widehat{PRQ}$ < $90^{\circ}$ be the minimum. we can easily investigate there's no point other than $R$ having such condition inside or on the triangle $\triangle PAQ$ and hence in the whole quadrilateral $APBQ$ which contains $C$.(how?)

so we find maximum 3 point having the condition in this option.

2.$\widehat{PAQ} = \widehat{PBQ} = 90^{\circ}$

in this option we can have only maximum two point have the condition and they must be $A$ and $B$.(why?)

so we find maximum 4 points on $C$ having the property which are edges of a rectangle containing $C$.

Comment: Either I don't understand your second sentence, or it is wrong...

Comment: @erz Which part do you mean?

Comment: I don't see how you can choose $l,l',h,h'$ so that $C$ is inside the quadrilateral formed by them.

Comment: If $P$ be a point on $C$ which has the property that when we rotate around it $90^\circ$ the rotated $C'$ has no intersection with $C$ then wa can find semilines $l,l'$ which $\angle lPl'$ =  $90^\circ$ and contains all of $C$ and therefore $Q$. This conclusion is also true for $Q$ as the same.

Comment: This is not true: $C$ can be narrow at $P$, but be very long and bend over $90^{0}$.

Comment: I can't Imagine ,you mean we can't find such $\angle lPl'=90^\circ$ containing $C$ in particular cases.I assumed it intuitively but I accept it needs proof also.

Comment: Draw the broken line by points like this: $(0,0)\to(0,2)\to(3,2)\to(3,-1)\to(2,-1)\to(2,1)\to(1,1)\to(1,0)\to(0,0)$.

Comment: generally, your proof is valid for a **convex** curve

Comment: @erz Amazing curve , you're true ,so what should we do with these mesmerizing non convex curves.